# Present Perfect and Past Simple

Tags: grammar

I have a question about the present perfect and the past simple. I think I know the basic concept about when to use the present perfect and when to use the past simple, but these examples are kind of making me confused so I'm wondering if I'm on the right track:

1. I've bought a new car. You need to come and see it.
2. I bought a new car last week.

I'm guessing the reason why the two situations are different comes from 'last week'. The 2nd sentence explicitly mentions 'last week', indicating the act of buying happened and ended last week, whereas the 1st sentence doesn't. Also the part "You need to come and see it" in the 1st sentence implies that I still own the car I bought, meaning that I didn't sell it or anything.

In my opinion these are the reasons why I need to use "have bought" and "bought" in each sentence. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Didn't you previoiusly ask the same question from the username Nederlanditis Nederlanditis? I read it yesterday and there were some comments, but now it's gone.

Comment: @Barmar Actually this is my first question on this website..

Comment: Very strange, since I'm sure the examples in the other question were also about buying a car. But the old question has been deleted.

Comment: Why does this belong to EL&U, rather than somewhere like Writing or English Language Learners?